# Calling an Instance method by the instance name as a String in java

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

In `class Tree` I got error message:

> The method removeparent() is undefined for the type String.

I want to convert string "Grandchild3" to object which instance MyTreeNode class, then I can use `removep("Grandchild3")`  call the method like this `Grandchild3.removeparent()`.
How can I do this?

Here's class MyTreeNode:

```
public class MyTreeNode<T>{
        private T data = null;
        private List<MyTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
        private MyTreeNode parent = null;

        public MyTreeNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void addChild(MyTreeNode child) {
            child.setParent(this);
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        public void addChild(T data) {
            MyTreeNode<T> newChild = new MyTreeNode<>(data);
            newChild.setParent(this);
            children.add(newChild);
        }

        public void addChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
            for(MyTreeNode t : children) {
                t.setParent(this);
            }
            this.children.addAll(children);
        }

        public List<MyTreeNode> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        private void setParent(MyTreeNode parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public MyTreeNode getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void removeparent() {
            this.parent = null;
        }
        public void removeChild(MyTreeNode<T> child)
        {
            this.children.remove(child);
        }

    }
```

Here's class Tree:

```
    public class Tree {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyTreeNode<String> root = new MyTreeNode<>("Root");

        MyTreeNode<String> child1 = new MyTreeNode<>("Child1");
        child1.addChild("Grandchild1");
        child1.addChild("Grandchild2");

        MyTreeNode<String> child2 = new MyTreeNode<>("Child2");
        child2.addChild("Grandchild3");

        root.addChild(child1);
        root.addChild(child2);
        root.addChild("Child3");

        root.addChildren(Arrays.asList(
                new MyTreeNode<>("Child4"),
                new MyTreeNode<>("Child5"),
                new MyTreeNode<>("Child6")
        ));

        for(MyTreeNode<String> node : root.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(node.getData());
        }

        printTree(root, " ");

        removep("Grandchild3"); //error message"The method removeparent() is undefined for the type String"

        printTree(root, " ");

    }

     private static void printTree(MyTreeNode<String> node, String appender) {
         System.out.println(appender+node.getData());
         for (MyTreeNode each : node.getChildren()){
             printTree(each, appender + appender);
         }
    }

     public static void removep(MyTreeNode<String> node)
        {
         node.getParent().removeChild(node);
         node.removeparent();

        }

}
```

Comment: `removep` has one parameter of type `MyTreeNode<String>`. You are passing it a string in the line `removep("Grandchild3");`. A `String` is not the same as a `MyTreeNode<String>`.

Comment: @TT yes, that's my question. how to figure it out?

Comment: Just guessing: call `removep(new MyTreeNode<>("Grandchild3"));`?

Comment: @TT not work ， cus that means you create a new one，but not the one witch I want to remove.

Comment: Well... `root.removeChild(new MyTreeNode<>("Grandchild3"));`. You are missing an `Object.equals` implementation in your `MyTreeNode` class though.

Comment: @TT excuse me for my abrupt questions. what means "Object.equals implementation in your MyTreeNode"? i'm confuse

Comment: Since the implementation of `MyTreeNode<T>.removeChild` does `this.children.remove(child);`, the `MyTreeNode` class will need an override for `Object.equals` to succeed. This equals implementation would just compare the `data` field.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is to convert a string to a class object. Now there are probably several ways it could be done, but in the context used here it seems like you could simply pass the appropriate object instead of messing with strings.

So in your case, the most appropriate way to do so would be to create a method which receives a string name and the top node of your tree and iterates over the tree to find the node with the given name. When found the method returns the node.

Then you can use that method to get the node from the name and then call `removep`.